# Haskell HashTable help rewrite using State monad

Tags: haskell, hashtable, state

So, here is my clumsy code implementing chained HashTable in Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Array(Array(..), array, bounds, elems, (//), (!))
import Data.List(foldl')
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad.State

class HashTranform a where
    hashPrepare :: a -> Integer

instance HashTranform Integer where
    hashPrepare = id 

instance HashTranform String where
    hashPrepare cs = fromIntegral (foldl' (flip ((+) . ord)) 0 cs)


divHashForSize :: (HashTranform a) => Integer -> a -> Integer
divHashForSize sz k = 1 + (hashPrepare k) `mod` sz 


type Chain k v = [(k, v)]

chainWith :: (Eq k) => Chain k v -> (k, v) -> Chain k v
chainWith cs p@(k, v) = if (null after) then p:cs else before ++ p:(tail after)
  where (before, after) = break ((== k) . fst) cs


chainWithout :: (Eq k) => Chain k v -> k -> Chain k v
chainWithout cs k = filter ((/= k) . fst) cs 


data Hash k v = Hash {
    hashFunc   :: (k -> Integer)
  , chainTable :: Array Integer (Chain k v) 
} 

--type HState k v = State (Hash k v)

instance (Show k, Show v) => Show (Hash k v) where
    show = show . concat . elems . chainTable


type HashFuncForSize k = Integer -> k -> Integer

createHash :: HashFuncForSize k -> Integer -> Hash k v
createHash hs sz = Hash (hs sz) (array (1, sz) [(i, []) | i <- [1..sz]])


withSlot :: Hash k v -> k -> (Chain k v -> Chain k v) -> Hash k v
withSlot h k op
    | rows < hashed = h
    | otherwise     = Hash hf (ht // [(hashed, op (ht!hashed))])
  where hf     = hashFunc h
        ht     = chainTable h
        rows   = snd (bounds ht) 
        hashed = hf k


insert' :: (Eq k) => Hash k v -> (k, v) -> Hash k v
insert' h p@(k, v) = withSlot h k (flip chainWith p)


delete' :: (Eq k) => Hash k v -> k -> Hash k v
delete' h k = withSlot h k (flip chainWithout k)


insert :: (Eq k) => Hash k v -> Chain k v -> Hash k v
insert src pairs = foldl' insert' src pairs


delete :: (Eq k) => Hash k v -> [k] -> Hash k v
delete src keys = foldl' delete' src keys


search :: (Eq k) => k -> Hash k v -> Maybe v
search k h
    | rows < hashed = Nothing
    | otherwise     = k `lookup` (ht!hashed) 
  where hf     = hashFunc h
        ht     = chainTable h
        rows   = snd (bounds ht)
        hashed = hf k
```

The problem is I don't want to have to code like this:

```
new = intHash `insert` [(1112, "uygfd"), (211, "catdied")]
new' = new `delete` [(1112, "uygfd")]
```

I believe it's modified with State Monad somehow, but having read online tutorials I couldn't quite grasp how exactly it's done.

So could you show me how to implement at least insert, delete, search or any one of them to give exposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the day your "state" will be a `Hash k v`. Let's break the interface functions into two groups. First are "state dependent" functions like `search k` which has a type like `Hash k v -> _` (where `_` just means "something"). Second are the "state updating" functions like `flip insert (k, v)` and `flip delete ks` which have types like `Hash k v -> Hash k v`.

As you've noted, you can already simulate "state" by manually passing around the `Hash k v` argument. The `State` monad is nothing more than type magic to make that easier.

If you look at `Control.Monad.State` you'll see `modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()` and `gets :: (s -> a) -> State s a`. These functions transform your "state updating" and "state dependent" functions into "`State` monad actions". So now we can write a combined `State` monad action like so

```
deleteIf :: (v -> Bool) -> k -> State (Hash k v) ()
deleteIf predicate k = do
  v <- gets $ search k
  case fmap predicate v of
    Nothing    -> return ()
    Just False -> return ()
    Just True  -> modify $ flip delete [k]
```

and then we can sequence together larger computations

```
computation = deleteIf (>0) 'a' >> deleteIf (>0) 'b'
```

and then execute them by "running" the `State` monad

```
runState computation (createHash f 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a great help!